# Is there a way to see a history of files that have been git stashed?

Tags: git, version-control

This is what happened:

- Made a lot of changes.
- Did a git stash
- git pull to get new files.
- Did a git stash pop, which lead to conflict.
- At some point I accidentally deleted my version of one of the files I changed.

Is there a way to look at the history of the file? It was stashed at one point. Is this stored anywhere?

Comment: It should still be in the stash.

Comment: To expand a bit on what @mkrieger1 said: If `git stash pop` has a merge conflict, it does not actually drop the saved stash commits. `git stash list` will still show it. A stash consists of two (or sometimes three) commits, and the name `stash` or `stash@{number}` refers to the main commit, so you can just get the file from `stash:path/to/file` (e.g., `git show stash:path/to/file`).

Answer (score 1):

To save your changes in the stash, run the command:

```
git stash save "OPTIONAL message for yourself"
```

To get your **most recent** stash after running `git stash`, use

```
git stash apply
```

To see a list of all your stashes, use

```
git stash list
```

You will get a list that looks something like this:

```
stash@{0}: WIP on master: 67a4e99 Merge branch1 to branch2
stash@{1}: WIP on master: 70a7a95 Add new user role
```

Choose a different git stash to restore with the number that shows up for the stash you want

```
git stash apply stash@{2}
```

You can also choose `git stash pop`, it works same as `git stash apply` like..

```
git stash pop
```

or

```
 git stash pop stash@{2}
```

[Git stash explained](https://www.google.ch/amp/s/www.freecodecamp.org/news/git-stash-explained/amp/)